# AWS Lambda function calling itself in .Net core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

When we work on AWS Lambda functions with node.js, we have a facility to recursively call the function using recursion again and again. This will give us the ability to run long running tasks.

See: [Write recursive AWS Lambda functions the right way | theburningmonk.com](https://theburningmonk.com/2017/08/write-recursive-aws-lambda-functions-the-right-way/)

I want to achieve the same while writing Lambda functions in .Net core 2.1. Is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: If you need to 'cheat' like this to run in Lambda, then your use-case is probably not a good fit for Lambda. What type of processing are you doing that will take more than 15 minutes? If you can describe your needs, we might be able to provide a more suitable alternative.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Its a long-running task involves running that reads data from Arora and elastic search and compare for different conditions. I have divided each condition in different batch and I want to call the same function again and again till the whole process completes.

Comment: Have you considered launching an Amazon EC2 instance and triggering the logic via User Data, then terminating when finished? An EC2 instance can cost as low as a few cents an hour and you won't have these types of restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course this same technique can be applied in C# as well as JS since it's intrinsic to the AWS Lambda service and nothing to do with the language or runtime. However, I'm not aware of any libraries that would help you here.  As with all recursion, you need to identify the recursive case and the base case.  The substantial difference being that the recursion with Lambda may be concurrent recursion (no need for it in your case, though it may be helpful to speed the process along), in which case you need to make use of the `Event` invocation model of the API.

Specific to your needs, and with respect to coding in C#, the `ILambdaContext` parameter to your function contains the same "time remaining" property as you find in the Node.js library.